# How to gather info from users with <textarea> JavaScript and save it? (website users uploading info)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a option for users to upload a youtubelink which will show on the page. The script should gain the .value of the textarea and send this to a var array of YouTube links.

Code:

```
var array=["npvNPORFXpc", "CcsUYu0PVxY", "dE_XVl7fwBQ", "iIwxR6kjTfA", "USe6s2kfuWk"];
var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
var previousRandom = "npvNPORFXpc"; // initial video
document.getElementById('random').addEventListener('click', function () {
do {
    var random = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
} while (previousRandom === random)
var url="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+random;
previousRandom = random;
iframe.src = url;});

document.getElementById('prevVideo').addEventListener('click', function () {
var curIndex = array.indexOf(previousRandom);
curIndex--;
if (curIndex < 0)
{
    curIndex = array.length -1;
}
var video = array[curIndex];
var url="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+video;
previousRandom = video;
iframe.src = url;
});
```

So I want users of my site to be able to add YouTube URL which the script should add to the var array. I don't know much of JavaScript but I've been trying all night and just can't find it out.

Check it out : http://jsfiddle.net/KgJ9J/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the data on the server, you will need a server side script. HTML as well as Javascript are processed on the client side. PHP might do it for you

Comment: Ouch.. so it isnt possible to save user data without a php? Than i gues i should start with php aswell any examples/sources you can give me? like http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_array.asp

Comment: write a file: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php
read a file: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

or you could use a database (but you still need to access it via PHP)

Comment: Thanks ill look into it and propably come back with some questions after :)